# unique chars with shift and operators : don't understand this code

Tags: java, operators, bit-shift

i don't understand the lines in the loop : we take the character and subtract `a`, so "10" ? (why?)
then `1 << val` : we shift 1 by val ? (why?)
and checker is 0, so how do we reach `> 0` in the condition?

```
    public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
    int checker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This code will work properly only when the string consists of lowercase characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code assumes that `str` is made of lower case letters and returns true if there are no repeating letters. It works like this:

`checker` is used as a bitmap, that is, each bit in this variable is used to keep track of one letter. Subtracting 'a' from the character gives 0 for 'a', 1 for 'b', 2 for 'c' etc. Shifting 1 left by this number gives 1 for 'a', 2 for 'b', 4 for 'c' etc.

By oring (`|`) this value with `checker` the code keeps track of previously encountered characters. So, if we encounter a second 'a' for example, `checker` has it's first bit set (which is tested by `&` in the if statement), so we know that `str` has duplicates.

In short, `checker` is used as a faster and more compact array of bool. This and similar techniques are called [bit manipulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation).

Comment: thanks cyco130, why don't we just check the number of the letter, without the "a" ? we would still have an ASCII number.. ? Also, i did not understand this : why do we use OR : `|`, as it could just add a `1` or `0` to `checker` , and we then check for a duplicate in the condition? Thanks ;-)

Comment: An `int` has only 32 bits. So it can hold information for only 32 different characters. By subtracting 'a' the code makes sure that the mapping is a->0, b->1, ..., z->25. By shifting 1 left by this amount you have this mapping (in binary): a->0001, b->0010, c->0100, etc. So each lowercase letter corresponds to a bit. ORing sets the bit. ANDing clears all other bits, so one can check if a particular bit is set. Try the links on wikipedia article linked in the answer or google "bit manipulation". C and C++ have the same bitwise operators so there should be plenty of introductory material around.

Comment: Addition wouldn't work. Suppose you've encountered an 'a'. You add 1, so you have a 1. Now suppose you've encountered a second 'a'. You add a 1 again and now you have a 2. This way you can't distinguish one 'b' from two 'a's.

Comment: Ok, on a second look, addition would work in this particular example since the duplicates are checked beforehand. Still using OR makes purpose clearer, at least to me :)

Comment: from the book "cracking the coding interview", p.193

Answer (score 1):

`str.charAt(i) - 'a'` returns, more or less, the "letter in the alphabet": if `str.charAt(i)` is `'a'`, this is `0`, if it's `'b'`, `val` is `1`, if it's `z`, `val` is `25`, and so on.

The rest of this is using a bit-twiddling technique: if the `val`th bit of `checker` is `1`, then we've seen the `val`th character already.  So `checker & (1 << val)` is nonzero if and only if the `val`th bit of `checker` is set, meaning we've already seen that character.  Otherwise, we set the `val`th bit of `checker` and continue the loop.

Comment: Thanks Louis, can i ask you some questions? why don't we just check the number of the letter, without the "a" ? we would still have an ASCII number.. ? Also, i did not understand this : why do we use OR : |, as it could just add a 1 or 0 to checker , and we then check for a duplicate in the condition? Thanks ;-)

Comment: An `int` only has room for 32 bits, but ASCII values can go up to 255, so we don't have room for all possible ASCII values.  It would be equivalent to say `+ (1 << val)` instead of `| (1 << val)`, but `|` is slightly more intuitive here, since we're basically using it as a bitmask rather than for arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old but I think my answer is correct and clearer.
We are dealing with lower case letter only in this case.
Like Paul asked, `(1 << val)` means Shift 1 by 'val' not shift 'val' by one. So for example, 'hello' gives:

```
1st loop: val = 111 in binary, 7 in decimal
          1 << val = 10000000  <-- here one is shifted by 7
          checker = 10000000 
2nd loop: val = 100 in binary, 4 in decimal
          1 << val = 10000
          checker = 10010000
3rd loop: val = 1011 in binary, 11 in decimal
          1 << val = 100000000000
          checker = 100010010000
4th loop: val = 1011 in binary, 11 in decimal
          1 << val = 100000000000
         (checker & (1 << val)) gives 100000000000 which is greater than 0
The loop is over because 'l' is not unique after 'hel' in 'hello'.
```

I hope this clears things.
I have the source code if you'd like to see exactly what's happening.

```
public class one_one_one {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String chars = "hello"; 
    if (isUniqueChars(chars)) {
        System.out.println("Unique");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Unique");
    }
    }

    public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
    int checker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(val)); //debug printout
        int temp = 1 << val;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(temp)); //debug printout
        System.out.println(checker & (1 << val)); //debug printout
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) {
        return false;
        }
        checker |= (1 << val);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(checker)); //debug printout
        System.out.println(' '); //debug printout
    }
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially, this is doing the same check as the previous sample with 128 with boolean array. This only checks for lower cases, instead of the whole ascii characters like the previous sample.

Comment: very nicely explained.