# hard to understand these java function

Tags: java

This is a function to check if the string is composed of unique chars, but I am not able to understand how it works. Thanks for help!

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
        if (str.length() > 256) {
            return false;
        }
        int checker = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
            if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
            checker |= (1 << val);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This checks whether a string is composed of unique characters or not. More specifically, it returns true if any given character appears in the string ``str`` at most once.

Comment: Java characters aren't 8 bits. This code looks incorrect to me.

Comment: It's not a very good implementation anyway. The early exit is wrong because there are more than 256 distinct characters as @ElliottFrisch already pointed out, and this will only detect duplicate lowercase letters and the characters {,|,},~ and DEL plus some other control char...

Comment: Looks like you might need to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: If you just dump a task on us, you won't get good response. Show people here that you have put effort towards solving your problem.

Comment: ewwww, bitwise operations for something that doesn't need them. Also bitwise operation inside an evaluation. It's hard to debug badly written code.

Comment: @KozRoss: Only a small subset of characters are checked, those being from 'a' through '\u0080' inclusive. I'm guessing the assumption is that the string only contains lower case letters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unique chars with shift and operators : don't understand this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784668/unique-chars-with-shift-and-operators-dont-understand-this-code)

Comment: Wow, looks like someone took the bad code from that question and made it even worse by adding the early exit...

Comment: I Googled "isUniqueChars checker" and found this code snippet all over the Internet, sometimes in sites that are about "code practice" or interview questions.  The earliest is a C version at http://analgorithmaday.blogspot.com/2011_04_04_archive.html which does stipulate that the string contains only lower-case letters.  Under this condition, the early exit should be comparing the length for 26, not 256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the purpose of this function is to take string with only lower case letters (a-z) in it and check whether all symbols are unique, ie it will return true for `abc` and return false for `abca`

this is done in next way:

1. for each symbol from string we're calculating it order number in alphabet, so `a` becomes `0`, `b` becomes `1`, `z` will become `25`
2. we have variable `checker` which is used as [mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) to store bit, each bit means that we've met some symbol from alphabet
3. to set/test bit in this variable they're using bitshift `1 << val`

so, to understand this function fully I suggest you to read about bit masks and bit arithmetic